# How to count the occurrence of a specific string in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, word-count

I installed the TextFX plugin and I see the option to get the word count for selected portion of text in a file.

How can I count the number of occurrences of a specific string within a selected portion of text?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Paste your selection in a new tab
- Press Ctrl+F
- Type your word, string, or phrase into the "Find what" box
- Click "Count"

Comment: Thank you. I needed to find out how many URL Rewrite rules were inside the web.config file, which did the trick. 109 rules, and will grow to more in the future. HUGE Website.

Answer (score 6):

#### How can I count the number of occurrences of a string within a text selection?

> I installed the TextFX plugin and I see the option to get the word count for selected portion of text in a file.

You don't need the TextFx plugin for this:

- Menu "Search" > "Mark".
- Set "Find what" to the string you want to count.
- Enable "In selection".
- Click "Mark All".
- The bottom of the dialog will update with "Mark: *n* matches.
- Click "Clear all marks" to remove the marks.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Seems like a lot of extra work. At that point I'd rather just paste the selection into a new window and Ctrl+F Count.

Comment: That's extra work. 1/ Copying the selection 2/ Creating a new tab 3/ Pasting the selection which is two steps more than my answer.

Comment: The extra steps are all keyboard shortcuts that most people know. Don't pretend like clicking through random menus is as convenient as Ctrl+C Ctrl+N Ctrl+V

Comment: Most people know their way around the "random" menus as well.

Comment: Chalk it up to different (key)strokes for different folks and let it go, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Without the hassle of counting by hand or of installing anything additional :
Search and replace by itself and Replace all. This will effectively give you the number of occurrences replaced without actually changing anything.